# Sublime text 3 using massive amount of CPU on idle

Tags: sublimetext3, cpu-usage

I'm running Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10, with all my installed packages disabled. On idle, it is taking up ~31% of my CPU with one file opened. This seems like a ridiculous amount for a text editor - why is this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This seems to be caused by indexing:

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/537

https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/file-indexing

Try adding

`"index_files": false`

in your configuration

Answer (score 12):

Sublime text gives you an **interface to check indexing status**.

Go to **Menu Help** -> **Indexing status**.

[image]

Comment: Is that a menu item that can be enabled somewhere, or is it just not available in the Linux version? Anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

It is due to the index files problem. Just disable that. This can be completely disabled by adding "index_files": false, to your Preferences.sublime-settings (Preference > Settings).

Comment: Before disabling it completely it would be nice to know the drawbacks of disabling it. What is the file indexing actually used for?

Answer (score 3):

You can throttle indexing by changing

```
"index_workers": 0 // Automatic worker spawning based on CPU
```

to

```
"index_workers": 1 // One worker only
```

in your user settings JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Find plugin Host
3. Open information
4. Open files and ports
5. Search for /Users//Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
6. Deactivate them

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that does not require disabling indexing is to exclude "Heavy" directories from being indexed. Add in preferences:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": [
        "node_modules",
        "a_heavy_directory_name"
    ]
```

from: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/537#issuecomment-237580498