# Sublime text 3 using 100% CPU on idle and with index set to false

Tags: sublimetext3

This is not a duplicate of
[Sublime text 3 using massive amount of CPU on idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722309/sublime-text-3-using-massive-amount-of-cpu-on-idle)

Here is why

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

I only use Sublime as a file editor and not a code IDE, meaning I mostly have unsaved tabs open with plain english test. But Yes, I have folders open on the side, all folders contain different language code and xml files. none are 'compilable' projects though, just standalone python, php or shell scripts.

Index is false and package control has only 2 packages

```
{
"bootstrapped": true,
"in_process_packages":
[
],
"installed_packages":
[
    "Material Theme",
    "Package Control",
],
}
```

No idexing is running
[image]

BUT still the CPU is at 100% most of the time. any more info I can check as to why is it so, please let me know

[image]

Comment: Do you have any folders open in the side bar, or do you only open files?

Comment: Yes, I have folders open on the side, all folders contain different language code and xml files. none are 'compilable' projects though

Comment: regardless of the state of indexing, if you add folders to the sidebar than Sublime will crawl all of the folders within to find all files so that it can add them to the file catalog (which powers `Goto Anything`). The sidebar is meant to show you the files relevant to your current project/task and not be a generic file tree, so potentially if you opened something like the root of your home directory, memory and CPU usage will spike way up as Sublime has to both find every file in that folder, as well as watch them all for updates